# selenium python stop element during test on chrome

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am able to run selenium tests but during one of the test when I click on edit button it's suppose to open page in edit mode, but instead of that I see loading icon and I can see page loading in back. But since loading icon is in front I can't click on any of the items in back. I see element as below, can I stop it?

```
<div class="ui-edit-loading">
     <img src="/img/loading.gif" alt="Loading...">
     <div>Loading ...</div>
</div>
```

On top of this element there is script as below not sure if that's related

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     test.Portal = window.Portal;   
     test.EventEmitter.instance.emit("testAPI");
</script>
```

Comment: I added `time.sleep()` to give it time to load but it never loads, if I run it manually it works fine, so thought was to stop it and continue with operations.

Comment: Show `HTML` of the target button and also code you try to click on it